# Get & Parse Facebook Graph API's JSON with Classic ASP

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, asp-classic

I am currently coding in classic ASP (due to the unavailability of PHP and ASP.NET on my client's servers). So my client has a Facebook page and I want to display his latest post on his website with JQuery.

My problem is now that Facebook recently changed the procedure, so you need an Auth code to even access public feeds, so I was wondering how could I get it done, to just read out the first feed of his Facebook page with ASP.

Maybe somebody here already tried that, I mean I already did that a hundred times in PHP5.3 but I am pretty new to good ol' classic ASP.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already did it with php then it should be really easy to get it working with asp (Classic or .net), since the facebook api is based on simple http requests.

Another thing is that googling "facebook classic asp" will return enough information for you to *at least* get started.
Just the top results:

- [Classic ASP and Facebook Graph API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/333706/Classic-ASP-and-Facebook-Graph-API)
- [Post to facebook wall with classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890751/post-to-facebook-wall-with-classic-asp)